# Trying to send vector over tcp

Tags: c++, serialization, vector, tcp

Im trying to send a receive and multidimensional vector with tcp in c++, but I keep on getting a segmentation fault. I'm trying to send one vector at a time instead of individual integers to reduce latency. I was wondering how I am supposed to serialize and deserialize a vector (without any libraries like Boost)

Server:

```
vector< vector<int> > contours = { {3,6,8}, {7,24,64}, {87,399} };
int len = 3;
int size =0;

while(waitKey(10) != 'q')
{      

    send(new_socket, &len, sizeof(int),0); //send size of vector 

    for(int i =0; i< len; i++){

        size = (contours[i].size() * sizeof(int)) + 24; //byte amount to send and receive

        send(new_socket, &size, sizeof(int), 0);
        send(new_socket, &contours[i], size, 0);
    } 
}
```

Client:

```
vector< vector<int> >contours;
vector<int> lines;
int contoursize =0;
int size =0;

while(waitKey(100) != 'q'){

    read(sock,&contoursize, sizeof(int));
    contours.resize(contoursize);

    for(int i =0; i< contoursize; i++){
        read(sock, &size, sizeof(int));


         cout<<" size: "<<size<<endl;

        read(sock, &lines, size);
        contours[i]= lines;
    }
}
```

Comment: `read(sock, &lines, size);` - you are overwriting the structure of the `vector` itself, not reading into the buffer it holds. But why don't you want to use a library? The Standard Library doesn't provide any proper serialisation mechanism, so using some other widely used library is the right thing to do.

Comment: Why the +24? And you can’t just read random data into an object. You have to send the *contents* and read into the contents. That’s why it’s probably exploding

Answer (score 2):

With `send(new_socket, &contours[i], size, 0)` you send the actual `std::vector` object in `contours[i]`, you don't send its data. And a `std::vector` object is effectively just a wrapper around a pointer and a size. And you can't send pointers over the network.

You need to send the actual *data* of each vector:

```
for (auto const& sub_vector : contours)
{
    // First send the number of elements
    uint32_t number_elements = sub_vector.size();
    send(new_socket, &number_elements, sizeof number_elements, 0);

    // Then send the actual data
    send(new_socket, sub_vector.data(), sub_vector.size() * sizeof sub_vector[0], 0);
}
```

<sub>[Error checking omitted, but you really should have it.]</sub>

I also recommend that you don't use a type like `int`, as its size isn't actually fixed. If you want unsigned 32-bit integers use `uint32_t`. Of course, you can use `int` internally in your program, and the convert the data to a portable fixed-size type for the transmission, as long as the receiving side can do the opposite conversion.

---

Furthermore I recommend that you also send the number of sub-vectors you want to send, so that the receiving side will know it beforehand:

```
uint32_t number_vectors = contours.size();
send(new_socket, &number_vectors, sizeof number_vectors, 0);

for (...) { ... }
```

On the receiving side you could do something like

```
// Receive the number of sub-vectors
uint32_t number_vectors;
recv(sock, &number_vectors, sizeof number_vectors, 0);

// Create the vectors
std::vector<std::vector<int>> contours(num_vectors);

// Read all sub-vectors
for (auto& sub_vector : contours)
{
    // Receive the amount of values
    uint32_t number_elements;
    recv(sock, &number_elements, sizeof number_elements, 0);

    // Create the sub-vector
    sub_vector = std::vector<int>(number_elements);

    // Receive the sub-vector data
    recv(sock, sub_vector.data(), sub_vector.size() * sizeof sub_vector[0], 0);
}
```

<sub>[Note: Again error checking omitted, but should really be there.]</sub>